# How to start JBOSS 7 in debug mode?

Tags: jboss7.x

I am getting an error(JBAS014750) when i deploy an app in JBOSS 7.So i need to run it in debug mode to find the exact issue.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using? I mean are you using Jboss through eclipse or command line?

Comment: You should always start JBoss in debug mode through eclipse.

Answer (score 39):

If you have a look at `bin/standalone.sh`you will discover

```
# Use --debug to activate debug mode with an optional argument to specify the port.
# Usage : standalone.bat --debug
#         standalone.bat --debug 9797
```

So, following this, just run the script with the `--debug <port>` parameter.

Comment: In my opinion, that's the easiest way! Plus, by this way it is possible to configure different ports for different cluster nodes which isn't possible when setting it globally in standalone.conf. +1

Comment: I had to define also the address this way: `--debug 0.0.0.0:8081`

Answer (score 21):

Edit the file <jboss-root>/bin/standalone.conf like this:

Uncomment the line

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4242,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Afterwards start the server with standalone.sh.

Now you can detach a debugger with your favorite IDE.
If you are using Eclipse you can switch to "Debug-Configurations" and add a new Remote Java-Application.

If the server is started with the `JAVA_OPTS` set above, you are able to debug with your IDE.

Comment: Its not advisable to edit the standalone.sh, rather you can modify JAVA_OPTS before executing the standalone.sh/domain.sh

Comment: I edited `<jboss-root>/bin/standalone.conf` and as far as I know this is the [recommended](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UsingJPDAToDebugTheASSourceCode) way to debug JBoss 7.

Comment: Oh.. My bad. I miss-read it, read standalone.sh instead of standalone.conf. Yup you are right with your answer. :-)  #peace

Comment: For those using the Windows version, the configuration file is `<jboss-root>\bin\standalone.conf.bat`.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using command line , then follow the guide here.

[How to start As7 in debug](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UsingJPDAToDebugTheASSourceCode)

If using eclipse , right click on server and select debug to start server in debug profile.

[image]

Comment: Red Hat has now destroyed all JBoss documentation links and hidden them behind their own unusable portal. Luckily, I was able to locate this article in the archive: https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-17532